# UIButton image not showing up on normal state

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uikit, xcode7

I am trying to have a checkbox using button and this is what I am doing:

```
int checkBoxWidth = foregroundHeight / 12.0;
int checkBoxHeight = foregroundHeight / 12.0;
UIButton* checkBox = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, checkBoxWidth, checkBoxHeight)];
//[checkBox setBackgroundImage:[Utility getEmptyCheckBoxOutIcon] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[checkBox setBackgroundImage:[Utility getCheckBoxOutIcon] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[checkBox setImage:[Utility getEmptyCheckBoxOutIcon] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[checkBox setImage:[Utility getCheckBoxOutIcon] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

checkBox.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
checkBox.layer.borderColor = [Utility primaryColor].CGColor;
checkBox.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
[switchView addSubview:checkBox];
```

but the image appears only when I touch the button, in any other state image is not showing up. Is there something missing?

Comment: What are you doing on button click, also upload that code.

Comment: If your button type is system , change it to custom

Comment: @sanjeet, I will upload the button click code but at this point that shouldn't matter right ? Even if I don't have button click, the image should show for normal state, isnt it ? what's baffling is that the image shows only whlie I touch the button, after that it disappears. again.

Comment: @vishnuvarthan the button is `UIButton* checkBox` can you give an example of what you meant?

Comment: UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

Comment: @vishnuvarthan tried. It still have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the button state for the image to be changed. Use the below code to achieve your desired result.

```
int checkBoxWidth = foregroundHeight / 12.0;
int checkBoxHeight = foregroundHeight / 12.0;
UIButton* checkBox = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, checkBoxWidth, checkBoxHeight)];
[checkBox setImage:[Utility getEmptyCheckBoxOutIcon] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[checkBox setImage:[Utility getCheckBoxOutIcon] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[checkBox setImage:[Utility getCheckBoxOutIcon] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[checkBox setImage:[Utility getCheckBoxOutIcon] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
[checkBox addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
checkBox.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
checkBox.layer.borderColor = [Utility primaryColor].CGColor;
checkBox.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
[switchView addSubview:checkBox];
```

And add this target function

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender{

sender.selected = !sender.selected;

}
```

Comment: That's not the issue, the button should show up in first place. The issues is not that the button isnt showing up. Button shows up but the tint is not getting applied. so that white button and white background looks same. The actual issues it `checkBox.tintColor = [Utility primaryColor];` not working. The other issue was button was being added to a subview. So your first answer did help in debugging :)